# Separate a input into 2 parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a web site and i wanna separate a input into two parts (two dropdown lists) and after that concatenate them together and afterwards put that value into my database.

It goes something like this:

I want users to input a product Age, and i want to give them a dropdown list where they can select a number and a dropdown list where they can select if it's a day, week or month. 
So they can select something like "1" + "day" or "4" + "weeks", and have a "1 day" or "4 weeks" in my Age database column. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, and maybe OT, but I would suggest you use a Date column in your database. This will allow you you to perform comparisons (like before / after), and ordering in SQL.

You can always the `distance_of_time_in_words` and `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` helpers ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)) to generate human readable time like 4 days ago, etc.

Comment: not helping me, i am aware of these methods but i don't need to specify the time so strictly, so a date type wouldn't be helpful. any other suggestions? i just want to know how to separate a input into two pieces